# A question about the Laplace transform of the probability distribution function

Tags: statistics, random-variables, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions

I am an undergraduate, who has just begun getting into probability theory. Recently we learned of the moment generating function of a random variable can be used to find moments, and the moment generating function is defined as

$$ MGFx(t) =  E[e^{tX}] =\begin{cases} \sum e^{tx}p(x), & \text{if X is discrete}\\ \int e^{tx}f(x)dx,\ & \text{if X is continuous} \end{cases}$$ 
The moment generating function can also be viewed as a Laplace transform of the probability density function of the random variable X, by replacing *s* with *-t*,

$${\scr L}(pdf(X))=M_X(t)=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{xt}\,dt$$

From here, one may take derivations with respect to *t* of $M_x(t)$, and then evaluate the derivative at t = 0, to find the respective moment of the probability distribution function, i.e.

$$ \frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}\ M_x(t) = M^n_X(t) $$
$$ M^n_X(0) = E[X^n], n =1,2,3,...$$
When I have dealt with the Laplace transform of a function in the past, for differential equations, the text stated that the transform redefines a function $f(t)$ such that the function is now defined by a complex variable s, where $s = \sigma +i\omega$, and

$${\scr L}(f(t))=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt =F(s)$$

For the majority of differential equations that I have dealt with, that involve a Laplace transform to solve, we are converting to from a function of time(t) to one of frequency(s), and the transformed function now has computation done on it in the complex frequency domain until the transform is reversed.

My question is that for the Laplace transform of a probability distribution function, what does the complex domain that the function is transformed to represent? More specifically what is the variable "t" that is introduced, and what is the meaning of the derivative of the moment generating function, with respect to t? Is the variable t arbitrary or is it the representation of something?

Thank you.

Comment: Two comments.  The mgf is 2-sided, taking into account both positive and negative valued random variables, while the Laplace transform is 1-sided.  More importantly, the mgf might not exist because the exponential function makes the integral blow up.  But the $t$ variable saves the day. The mgf always exists on the imaginary axis, because $\exp( i t X)$ is bounded for real $t$ and $X$.  The function $\phi_X(t) = M_X(it)$ is thus important enough to have a name, it is the *characteristic function* of the rv $X$, and has complete information about the distribution of $X$ packed in it.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I should have generalized and spoke about the bilateral Laplace transform instead. What does a derivation with respect to _**t**_ represent though? Is it just an arbitrary correction variable that has nice properties or does it represent something in the probability space? Thank you for your response!

Comment: You might as well ask the same questions about $s$ in Laplace transforms.  The characteristic function $phi_X(t) = E\exp(itX)$ exists for all real $t$ and for all random variables, so it's more useful in theoretical contexts.  You can think of it as the Fourier transform of the probability law of $X$ (say, of the density function of $X$), so whatever meaning the FT variable has in general, $t$ has it in the case of characteristic functions of random variables.  If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, for example, $\phi_{X+Y}(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t)$.

Comment: Okay, I believe this is becoming clearer now. The variable t exists as the argument of the characteristic function, which makes the recovery of moments easier. Sort of like the logarithmic multiplication trick (log(ab) = log(a) +log(b)). The variable t is not necessarily one with a name (like time, frequency, etc.), it just exists as as a variable of a complex function that has unique ties to the distribution, and makes the computation simpler.

Comment: Yes.  (Not that identification of moments is the be-all and end-all of probability theory, though.)

Comment: Thank you for your help!